# Xamarin.android app only opens directly from play store

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my xamarin.forms android app I am facing a strange issue. I published my app on playstore and in certain devices , when we download the app and open directly from playstore, it will navigate to Mainpage and work as intented. But when we open the app from phones launcher a white screen will show after splashpage and will stuck at there.If we get back to playstore and open the installed app from there , it works. I noticed this issue in all VIVO phones and some samsung devices(these are the only ones I have currently access). But in my huawei honor 8X no issue .

What will be the cause of this problem?

**My release configuration.**

```
Enable Multi-Dex  -- True

Android Package format -- apk

Dex compiler -- dx

Code shrinker -- None

Linking -- Sdk Assemblies Only

Supported architecture -- armeabi-v7 , arm64-v8a 

Minimum android version -- Android 7.0

Target android  Version -- Android 9.0
```

Comment: Your best bet would be to attach the debugger and try reproducing it on the device you are seeing this behavior

Comment: @zafar Yes you were right